# How do you load a new NIB file during autorotate?

Tags: ios, autorotate, glkit

Apple's NIBs don't support rotation natively, so I'm trying to use two different NIBs for the same view - one for each orientation.

I tried the following, and it works, except ... it breaks some subviews (e.g. Apple's OpenGL / GLKit views).

It ONLY breaks the very first rotation - all subsequent rotations work exactly as expected. So, I'm assuming there's a subtlety in Apple's stack of "viewWill/Did" calls that I'm missing here. Problem is, I've never been able to find real documentation on that - just vague references here and there inside Apple docs to "some of" the calls that happen, and when/why.

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( toInterfaceOrientation) )
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-landscape", NSStringFromClass([self class])] owner:self options:nil];

        [self viewDidAppear:FALSE];
        [self viewWillDisappear:FALSE];
        [self viewDidReload];
        [self viewWillAppear:FALSE];
        [self viewDidAppear:FALSE];

        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-landscape"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class])] owner:self options:nil];

        [self viewDidAppear:FALSE];
        [self viewWillDisappear:FALSE];
        [self viewDidReload];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-portrait"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self viewWillAppear:FALSE];
        [self viewDidAppear:FALSE];
    }

}
```

Comment: "Apple's NIBs don't support rotation natively" - where did you get that?

Comment: From the past 4 years of developing in Interface Builder: the vast majority of interfaces need re-layout on rotation - merely "squishing a few things, everything proportionately" is so far from being "sufficient" that it's pretty much totally useless. Works OK for iPad vs iPhone (barely), but terribly for landscape vs portrait.

Comment: ...and, sadly, Apple's new Layout system absolutely does not work (yet). With iOS 6.something it might work for real-world apps, but so far it breaks catastrophically (both in the editor and at runtime) on most examples I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: this appears to be a bug specifically in Apple's OpenGL code. It's only projects using GLKit that are affected:

Apple's GLKViewController has to be the sole view controller, taking the full area of the Container VC (e.g. UINavigationController/UITabController/window's rootViewcontroller) and must be managing precisely one GLKView - if there are any others, and/or the GLKViewController isn't full screen, it breaks autorotation. (there appears to be some tricks Apple is doing when the GLKVC is hooked up as the one running the show, which don't fire otherwise)

In theory, if you create a custom Container View Controller (the new feature from iOS 5 that's currently only partially documented by Apple), then it will work correctly. But until Apple publishes full docs for that (maybe WWDC next year?) that's very hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple, in your case you should not only load a different nib, but change the view controller:

> If you want to present the same data differently based on whether a
>   device is in a portrait or landscape orientation, the way to do so is
>   using two separate view controllers.

Read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) to find out how exactly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs - it's a recent change, I hadn't found that before. Unfortunately, this approach appears to require iOS 5, and a great deal of extra code (and it requires disabling auto-rotation and using Notifications instead). Also, the documentation is missing on the details of what will happen - it only gives an example for when you're using a specific kind of storyboard, and IME different storyboards change what happens for these events :(

Comment: Thanks for this. I belatedly remembered the main problem with this approach: it's technically incorrect, and in the long run it breaks reasonable assumptions other developers will have made (I've been down that path before :( ). Ultimately, it's deleting/reassigning all state for no reason - which causes lots of problems with NSNotification-based code. In complex apps, it can break some of Apple's other APIs (e.g. CoreData, which cannot change threads without a huge amount of work).

Answer (score 0):

If you search Stack Overflow for "[ios] rotate different nibs" you'll get a ton of hits. There are some, shall we say, "creative" solutions out there.

To Levi's point, as far back as iOS 4.3 at the very least, Apple's counsel has been "load a new controller with the orientation-specific NIB". In Xcode, you can install old iOS documentation sets, and if you look at the iOS 4.3 *View Controller Programming Guide,* and go to the "Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface" section, you'll see that their counsel back then is very similar to what we see now (though it's using NIBs and not storyboards). But the concept is the same. Fire up a new view controller if a different orientation. It's going to be the most robust approach, IMHO, as when I researched this a long time ago, it appeared that all of the techniques that involved loading the NIB in the background seemed to somewhat kludgy feel to them. Doing this modal to the landscape controller ensures that no critical system notifications or other operations slip through the cracks.

Personally, I find that enough of a hassle, that I have generally given up on separate NIBs for different orientations and stay with a single NIB/scene and rely on springs and struts (a.k.a. auto sizing masks) to do the vast majority of layout changes. And when I have a view for whose changes require more significant relocation of controls with respect to each other, changing of background images, etc, I'll programmatically change the layout in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (which, if iOS version is less than 5.0, I invoke from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` ... but for iOS 5 and later, `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is superior).

Comment: Hmm ... I wonder: maybe I could load a second NIB inside viewWillLayoutSubviews - but NOT hook up outlets - and programmatically "re-configure" all the existing in-memory objects using the frame's of their "new NIB" counterparts?